# Pandas: How to extract Datetime ranges from DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, range

I have a collection of `DatetimeIndex` objects such as

```
DatetimeIndex(['2007-11-01 00:00:00', '2008-01-01 00:00:00',
               '2008-02-01 00:00:00', '2008-03-01 00:00:00',
               '2008-04-01 00:00:00', '2012-09-01 00:10:00',
               '2012-09-01 00:20:00', '2012-09-01 00:30:00',
               '2012-09-01 00:40:00', '2012-09-01 00:50:00',
               ...
               '2012-09-30 22:40:00', '2012-09-30 22:50:00',
               '2012-09-30 23:00:00', '2012-09-30 23:10:00',
               '2012-09-30 23:20:00', '2012-09-30 23:30:00',
               '2012-09-30 23:40:00', '2012-09-30 23:50:00',
               '2012-10-01 00:00:00', '2015-07-01 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=4326, freq=None, tz=None)
```

Both its `freq` and `inferred_freq` are `None`, I think because even though the data in fact have a 10 minute period, this cannot be detected due to missing parts. It is just these missing parts, or, equivalently, available parts, which I want to extract as efficiently as possible. Namely, i'd like to get something such as the following list of ranges:

```
[('2007-11-01 00:00:00', '2007-11-01 00:00:00'),
 ('2008-01-01 00:00:00', '2008-01-01 00:00:00'),
 ('2008-02-01 00:00:00', '2008-02-01 00:00:00'),
 ('2008-03-01 00:00:00', '2008-03-01 00:00:00'),
 ('2008-04-01 00:00:00', '2008-04-01 00:00:00'),
 ('2012-09-01 00:10:00', '2012-10-01 00:00:00'),
 ('2015-07-01 00:00:00', '2015-07-01 00:00:00')]
```

How should I go about doing this? I have looked at `PeriodIndex`, but that seems to be for a different type of application, or perhaps just doesn't deal with arbitrary time intervals yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) by Series `grouper` and aggregate `min` and `max`:

`grouper` is created by comparing `difference` with `10 minute` and `cumsum`.

```
rng = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2007-11-01 00:00:00', '2008-01-01 00:00:00',
               '2008-02-01 00:00:00', '2008-03-01 00:00:00',
               '2008-04-01 00:00:00', '2012-09-01 00:10:00',
               '2012-09-01 00:20:00', '2012-09-01 00:30:00',
               '2012-09-01 00:40:00', '2012-09-01 00:50:00',
               '2012-09-30 22:40:00', '2012-09-30 22:50:00',
               '2012-09-30 23:00:00', '2012-09-30 23:10:00',
               '2012-09-30 23:20:00', '2012-09-30 23:30:00',
               '2012-09-30 23:40:00', '2012-09-30 23:50:00',
               '2012-10-01 00:00:00', '2015-07-01 00:00:00'])

s = pd.Series(rng)
grouper = s.diff().ne(pd.to_timedelta('10min')).cumsum()
print (grouper)
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     6
6     6
7     6
8     6
9     6
10    7
11    7
12    8
13    8
14    8
15    8
16    8
17    8
18    8
19    9
dtype: int32
```

```
print (s.groupby(grouper).agg(['min', 'max']).astype(str).apply(tuple, axis=1).tolist())
[('2007-11-01 00:00:00', '2007-11-01 00:00:00'), 
 ('2008-01-01 00:00:00', '2008-01-01 00:00:00'), 
 ('2008-02-01 00:00:00', '2008-02-01 00:00:00'), 
 ('2008-03-01 00:00:00', '2008-03-01 00:00:00'),
 ('2008-04-01 00:00:00', '2008-04-01 00:00:00'),
 ('2012-09-01 00:10:00', '2012-09-01 00:50:00'), 
 ('2015-09-30 22:40:00', '2015-09-30 22:50:00'), 
 ('2012-09-30 23:00:00', '2012-10-01 00:00:00'), 
 ('2015-07-01 00:00:00', '2015-07-01 00:00:00')]
```

Comment: I add new answer, please check it.

Comment: This works very nicely. I left out `astype(str)` because that translates to my local time zone; getting back `Timestamp` is fine.